# CSS Vertical middle and pull right/left element with unknown height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to place the items (glyphicon, arrows css, imgs) in the left or right side of my text in the TH element of bootstrap table and make sure they are automatically positioned vertically in the middle.

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th class="text-right">ID<span class="left-side glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></th>
                <th>COD<span class="right-side glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></th>
                <th class="text-right">ID<span class="left-side arrow-down"></span></th>
                <th>COD<span class="right-side arrow-down"></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

That way if given a value of top works well for the arrow element but with no for the item glyphicon.

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
th {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th > .left-side,
th > .right-side {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%; <-- Ok for arrow but not for glyphicon
}
th > .left-side {
  left: 5px;
}
th > .right-side {
  right: 5px;
}
.arrow-up {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 6px dashed;
  border-bottom: 6px solid \9;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
}
.arrow-down {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 6px dashed;
  border-top: 6px solid \9;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
 }
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/LChtJSf4tK#)

Is there any way to vertically align an element of any height, being able to place to the right or left of a text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `top:43%` use the following:

```
top: 50%;  /*moves the arrow down 50%*/
transform: translateY(-50%); /*moves it back up half its height*/
```

[Updated bootlply](http://www.bootply.com/LxVKuHz9Cs)

Comment: Perfect! Thank u very much!